# Must declare the scalar variable Error Message

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a search bar that uses this query. I'm getting the error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@a"

This error message comes up at all @a/@b/@c/@d. Anyone know what the error refers to?

```
SELECT [a],[b],[c],[d] 
FROM [dbo].table1 
WHERE (([a] LIKE '%' + @a + '%') 
       OR ([b] LIKE '%' + @b + '%') 
       OR ([c] LIKE '%' + @c + '%') 
       OR ([d] LIKE '%' + @d + '%'));
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].table1 
WHERE (([a] LIKE '%'+@a+'%') 
       OR ([b] LIKE '%'+@b+'%') 
       OR ([c] LIKE '%'+@c+'%') 
       OR ([d] LIKE '%'+@d+'%'));
```

The goal of the select should be to filter the users input and still from the rest of the table while showing the users input results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the Button call that I am trying to attach this too after I get it working in SQL Server.

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
        string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Imported_USPFOWEB_Pers_Unit_tbl WHERE (([upc] LIKE '%'+@upc+'%') OR  ([uname] LIKE '%'+@uname+'%') OR ([st_addr] LIKE '%'+@st_addr+'%') OR ([pr_nbr] LIKE '%'+@pr_nbr+'%'))";
        sqlcomm.CommandText = sqlquery;
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("upc", TxtSearch.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The error message when I run the site and press the button is as followed:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@uname".

Comment: How are you **calling** this query? From T-SQL code? From some other language? The code per se seems OK - I suspect it's a problem with the way you're trying to call / execute this query

Comment: I'll edit the post, with more information/code,but i'm just trying to do a query in SQL server as a simple select statement first. Than add it to some C# code i'm attaching this to.

Comment: You reference 4 parameters in your query but your code only creates one. And those leading wildcards are going to cause performance issues like crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling this from C#, you have to define **ALL** the placeholders as **parameters** of your call, and set the values in your C# code, before calling the query:

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
    sqlconn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
    string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Imported_USPFOWEB_Pers_Unit_tbl WHERE (([upc] LIKE '%'+@upc+'%') OR  ([uname] LIKE '%'+@uname+'%') OR ([st_addr] LIKE '%'+@st_addr+'%') OR ([pr_nbr] LIKE '%'+@pr_nbr+'%'))";
    sqlcomm.CommandText = sqlquery;
    sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;

    // =========================================
    // here, you need to set the values of **ALL** parameters in your query!
    // @upc, @uname, @st_addr, @pr_nbr 
    // =========================================
    // sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("upc", TxtSearch.Text);

    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@upc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtSearch.Text;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ".....";
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@st_addr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  ".....";
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@pr_nbr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  ".....";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    sda.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Also: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Instead use the code I've added above (and adapt as needed - those parameters might not all be `SqlDbType.VarChar`, or not all would be 50 characters long - just adapt to your situation).

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you marc_s. I'll give that link a read after I get out of the coding mood. I'm still learning and love this site! Thanks again.