# Problem with InsertCommand in SqlDataSource. ERROR: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'You must declare the scalar variable'@EXPEDIENTE'.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am a newbie and I have recently started working developing a web application, I do not have much experience so if you are able to solve the problem and explain it in detail I would be much more than grateful. I am trying to insert in Visual Studio through a Gridview a series of data in my database. For this I have several textboxes and a dropdownlist in the FooterRow to obtain a series of data and the other data that is missing in the insert I obtain it by looking at other GridViews/querying the database. At the end, after successfully obtaining all the data I need to insert through the SqlDataSource, I am ready to insert the data with cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); But when trying to do it I got this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'You must declare the scalar variable '@EXPEDIENTE'.'

My GridView code is :

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="723px" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="EXPEDIENTE,NUMERO_COMENTARIO" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EXPEDIENTE" SortExpression="EXPEDIENTE">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EXPEDIENTE") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EXPEDIENTE") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="Click_addUser" >Añadir Comentario</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NUMERO_COMENTARIO" SortExpression="NUMERO_COMENTARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NUMERO_COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NUMERO_COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FECHA" SortExpression="FECHA">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FECHA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FECHA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="FECHA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COMENTARIO" SortExpression="COMENTARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="COMENTARIO" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USUARIO" SortExpression="USUARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USUARIO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USUARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="NOMBRE_USUARIO" 
        DataValueField="NOMBRE_USUARIO" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DESAConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT A.ID_EXPE EXPEDIENTE,A.ID_COEX NUMERO_COMENTARIO, convert(varchar, A.FECHA_COMENTARIO, 3 ) FECHA, A.COMENTARIO,E.NOMBRE_USUARIO USUARIO FROM COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES A , EXPE_EXPEDIENTES B,CLIE_CLIENTES C,EXCL_EXPEDIENTES_CLIENTES D,USUA_USUARIOS E WHERE A.ID_EXPE = B.ID_EXPE AND B.ID_EXPE=D.ID_EXPE AND C.ID_CLIENTE=D.ID_CLIENTE AND E.ID_USUA=A.ID_USUA;" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] WHERE ([ID_EXPE] = @EXPEDIENTE) AND ([ID_COEX] = @NUMERO_COMENTARIO)"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] ([ID_EXPE], [ID_COEX], [FECHA_COMENTARIO], [COMENTARIO], [ID_USUA]) VALUES (@EXPEDIENTE,@NUMERO_COMENTARIO,@FECHA,COMENTARIO,@USUARIO)"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] SET [COMENTARIO] = @COMENTARIO, [ID_USUA] =(SELECT ID_USUA FROM USUA_USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO=@USUARIO) WHERE [ID_EXPE] = @EXPEDIENTE AND [ID_COEX] = @NUMERO_COMENTARIO">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="FECHA_COMENTARIO" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="COMENTARIO" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_USUA" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="FECHA_COMENTARIO" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="COMENTARIO" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_USUA" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the Code of the process that gets executed when i click on the "Añadir comentario" (Add comment in spanish) button is :

```
protected void Click_addUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool conected = false;

    try
    {
        conection.Close();
        conection.Open();
        conected = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string errorconection = ex.Message;
    }
    
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)GridView3.FooterRow;
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("DropDownList1");
  //  String nombre_usua = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("USUARIO")).Text;
    String nombre_usua=ddl.SelectedValue;
    String id_usua;
    String sSql = "select ID_USUA FROM USUA_USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO='" + nombre_usua + "'";

    SqlDataSource5.SelectCommand = sSql;
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource5.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    id_usua=dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    sSql = "select ID_EXPE FROM EXPE_EXPEDIENTES WHERE ID_EXPE="+GridView2.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text+"";
    SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = sSql;
    dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource6.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string id_Expe=dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    sSql = "select MAX(ID_COEX)+1 from COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES where ID_EXPE="+id_Expe+"";
    SqlDataSource7.SelectCommand = sSql;
    dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource7.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string id_Coex = dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] ([ID_EXPE], [ID_COEX], [FECHA_COMENTARIO], [COMENTARIO], [ID_USUA]) VALUES (@EXPEDIENTE, @NUMERO_COMENTARIO, @FECHA, @COMENTARIO,@USUARIO)", conection);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@EXPEDIENTE";
    param.Value = id_Expe;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@NUMERO_COMENTARIO";
    param.Value = id_Coex;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@FECHA";
    param.Value = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("FECHA")).Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@COMENTARIO";
    param.Value = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("COMENTARIO")).Text; ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


    SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@USUARIO";
    param.Value = id_usua;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param5);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

The error is on the  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

I am turning crazy trying to find a solution , if anyone could help me i would be so thankful.Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please help, i need help.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing which line is the error. There are a number of issues I can see: The XAML declare the `SqlDataSource` as having parameters such as `<asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE"`, but the actual SQL command uses `@EXPEDIENTE`. Meanwhile the C# code is caching the connection object, you should never do this. Instead, create the connection object when you need it and dispose it with a `using` block. Same goes for `SqlDataSource5`. You also reusing it and replacing the `SelectCommand`, you may as well use a new `SqlCommand` object and `ExecuteScalar`, which is much simpler. ....

Comment: .... And you have a major SQL injection issue, do not interpolate data into your queries, use parameters instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412440/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-message
try this or check your ID_EXPE is Primary_key or auto increment

Comment: @Charlieface i already found the problem. In the C# code i used the parameter param all the time and i needed to use param2 , param3, param4 etc.... Changed that and everything works perfect.

Comment: @AntonSolicitors You could answer your own question if you actually figure out the answer, if nobody has posted one yet. It seems from your comments that you may have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

i already found the problem. In the C# code i used the parameter param all the time and i needed to use param2 , param3, param4 etc.... Changed that and everything works perfect.